# Restore Bak file on other machine which doesn't have same directory structure?

Tags: sql-server-2005

```
 By default the database files will be restored to the directories from which they came
```

On computer **A** I Created a Bak file

*c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\Data\aaa.mdf*

Im going to computer **B** ( trying to restore the bak file )  ( to its **D drive** which contains its SQL folders)

and type : ( the folders are appropriate to the Computer **B**'s folders).

```
RESTORE DATABASE aaa FROM DISK = '\\dsmain\OLD_DB\aaa.bak'
WITH REPLACE , MOVE 'aaa' TO 'D:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\DATA\aaa.mdf',
MOVE 'aaa_log' TO 'D:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\DATA\aaa_log.ldf'
ALTER DATABASE aaa SET MULTI_USER
```

Result :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lD8u3.jpg

Even if i go to SMMS :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pIpC7.jpg

I can see that he's **searching his ORIGINAL PATH**.

Question :

How Do I tell him **programmatic**  , **not** to restore as its original location but **my** location ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
--check contents of backup file
restore FILELISTONLY from 
disk = 'c:\temp\mydatabase.bak'

--restore backup file
restore database mydatabase
from disk = 'c:\temp\mydatabase.bak'
with replace,
move 'mydatabase' to 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\mydatabase.mdf',
move 'mydatabase_log' to 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\mydatabase.ldf'
```